# Gmail: automatic forwarding of email headers, is it possible?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I'm trying to set an a Gmail account that automatically forwards incoming emails (specifically, mail delivery error messages) to other addresses in the company I work in. The Gmail account in question is a company (paid) Google account, so I have access to the Google Admin Panel.

The problem I have is that the users in the company use Outlook, including me. My work computer has Outlook configured with my work email, and should receive copies of these failed email reports, but I receive the email with no attachments, which normally would include the headers.

I suspect Gmail is sending attachments that Outlook cannot display, because I also use my personal phone, where I have my work email also configured in the email app. In there, I see that the emails arrive with an *.eml file attached. This file seems to correspond with the email headers, however, it's always blank if I open it, and it's only 3KB in size.

Now, the problem I have is that I need Gmail to include the email headers, because otherwise these reports are useless. I know you can see the email headers in Gmail webmail by going to each message individually, and then clicking on "Show Original", which then lets you download the headers as a separate *.eml file. However, this solution is not ideal, because it's cumbersome, and I need this to be automated.

I've seen suggestions that basically amount to "why don't you just use the Gmail webmail?", "just download the headers and send them manually", or "why not just use another desktop email client?". I hope you understand these suggestions don't work for me.

So I want to know: is it possible for a paid Gmail account to include the headers in an automated manner? Or is it possible (through the Admin Panel, with a plugin, or otherwise) to change the *.eml file to a plain text *.txt format? (Assuming that would solve the problem of them showing up as empty in Android, or not showing at all on Outlook).

Comment: "always blank if I open it, and it's only 3KB in size" -- _how_ are you opening it? It sounds like those 3KB are in fact just the email headers, without the body. (Which is just what I'd expect for delivery failure reports.)

Comment: I'm just opening the *.eml file in Android, with the default email app (in my case, it's the Samsung one) and it does show the addresses involved, but nothing else. The "from" field shows the _our_ Gmail address, and not the corresponding one that appears in the "reply-to" field when I open the email headers through Gmail webmail.

Comment: If you open it with a text editor instead, does that show the headers?

Comment: Yes, they show normally. Also, the webmail for our email server shows them as well, and in full detail. So, it's basically related to Outlook, and its inability to open *.eml files.

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect Gmail is sending attachments that Outlook cannot display, because I also use my personal phone, where I have my work email also configured in the email app. In there, I see that the emails arrive with an *.eml file attached.

According to your description, I noticed that you received the emails forwarded from Gmail in your work mailbox on the outlook client, but the .eml attachment of the emails disappeared, right?

If so, to further confirm whether the issue is related to the outlook client, please try to log in your work email to web mail, and check whether there's .eml attachment in the forwarded emails and whether .eml file can be opened normally. If the message on the web mail does not display attachments or the attachments cannot be opened normally, the problem may be related to the email itself.

If the .eml attachment can be displayed normally on web mail, if only. EML attachments in the message cannot be displayed on the outlook client? If so, considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

If this is still the issue in safe mode, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

In addition, antivirus software may conflict with outlook. It is suggested that you could temporarily close your antivirus software and restart outlook to check whether this problem still exists.

Hope the above help.

***Updated***:

According to my test on my Outlook client and Gmail web mail: I log in to my account (personal Gmail account) on Gmail web mail and set up to automatically forward the email with .eml attachment to my working account(Exchange account) configured on the Outlook client. After my work account receiving this email, I found that the .eml attachment is displayed normally and can be opened successfully.

In order to further confirm whether your problem is related to your Outlook client, please try to log in to your work account on other mailbox clients on your computer, such as mail, and check whether the .eml attachment of email can be received and opened normally.

If the issue still occur in Mail client, considering that everything is normal on web mail, the problem may be related to the synchronization between web mail and client. It's suggested that you could try to perform a clean boot for windows to check if there're any influence of other programs on your computer.

If the .eml attachment of email can be received and opened normally in Mail client, considering that the outlook program itself is corrupted, it's suggested that you could try to fix the office application or uninstall and reinstall office to check if there're any differences.

Comment: The *.eml files do show in the webmail client, and they show the headers properly when opened from there. Aside from that, I've tried your solutions before (restarting Outlook in safe mode, creating a new profile, etc), and none worked. My work computer doesn't have an antivirus, so it can't be that. The attachment is just completely missing in Outlook, and it doesn't even have a warning of a potentially-unwanted file at all.

Comment: Hi gaseoso, due to the word limit of comment, I have updated in my reply to the previous post. Please pay attention to check it.

Comment: I checked, and tried reinstalling. No difference. Installed on another laptop to check as well, but nothing there either.

It's come to my attention that Windows 10 also warns whenever I try to download an EML directly from Google, as it's identified as a potentially unwanted file. Makes me think Windows is deleting the attachments from my messages.

Comment: As you mentioned, windows will also issue a warning when you download the .eml file. This is most likely related to your .eml files itself.

Comment: Okay, but if you read the original question, I'm looking for a solution to this problem. Having an acknowledgement it's happening doesn't help me.